# Kubuntu 12.04 login screen

Tags: kubuntu, login

Is it possible to have a login screen for Kubuntu 12.04 where I can click a user's name instead of typing it in?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image]

**KDM**

If you are using the KDM:

KDE System Settings > Login Screen > Theme

Install and pick a theme with the user list - here is one: http://kde-look.org/content/show.php/Kubuntu+Sitter+KDM?content=150704

[image]

**LightDM**

If you are using the lightdm-kde-greeter. Earlier: https://www.kubuntuforums.net/showthread.php?57401-Lightdm-KDE

KDE System Settings > Login Screen (LightDM) > Theme - Pick a theme with the user list

[image]

Comment: OK I got the lightdm-kde-greeter installed, but how do I change the background image for the User Bar?  The default background is, let's just say, really UGLY!

Comment: With the Kubuntu 12.04 the User Bar doesn't have the gui to set the background. You could edit the /usr/share/kde4/apps/lightdm-kde-greeter/themes/userbar/main.qml -> The line 34 'source: plasmaTheme.wallpaperPath()' change it to the 'source: "/path/to/my-wallpaper.png"' . Older Kubuntu forums link: https://www.kubuntuforums.net/showthread.php?60355-LightDM-KDE